# Openoffice yum repo for RHEL 5?

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, openoffice

We need to run Openoffice as a service so that **unoconv** can be used convert Word documents to PDF. Any yum repositories for Openoffice in **RHEL 5** server ?

Answer (score -1):

I see unoconv specifically in the DAG repo:

```
$ yum info unoconv
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Available Packages
Name       : unoconv
Arch       : noarch
Version    : 0.4
Release    : 1.el5.rf
Size       : 70 k
Repo       : dag
Summary    : Tool to convert between any document format supported by OpenOffice
URL        : http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/
License    : GPL
Description: unoconv converts between any document format that OpenOffice understands.
           : It uses OpenOffice's UNO bindings for non-interactive conversion of
           : documents.
           :
           : Supported document formats include Open Document Format (.odf),
           : MS Word (.doc), MS Office Open/MS OOXML (.xml),
           : Portable Document Format (.pdf), HTML, XHTML, RTF, Docbook (.xml),
           : and more.
```

Here's the DAG FAQ on getting their repo up and running: http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php#B

The RPM itself is at: http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/dag/RPMS/unoconv-0.4-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm

Comment: Yes unoconv is available in the repo, but not Open-office which a dependency for unoconv

Comment: @nitins I see Open Office RPMS in the CentOS 5.8 updates repo: http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5.8/updates/i386/RPMS/ but you probably don't want to install that repo if you're running RHEL.  Possibly, you can cherry pick RPMs.